# RegEx Statement Issues - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to use RegEx to strip down the following data:

```
mlb_s_left1=Baltimore 3   ^NY Yankees 12 (FINAL)&mlb_s_right1_1=W: Hughes L: Britton&mlb_s_right1_count=1&mlb_s_url1=http://sports.espn.go.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=320801110&mlb_s_left2=^Chicago Sox 3   Minnesota 2 (FINAL)&mlb_s_right2_1=W: Peavy L: Diamond S: Reed&mlb_s_right2_count=1&mlb_s_url2=http://sports.espn.go.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=320801109
```

I am hoping to split it apart by home team (first city), home score (first digit), away team (second city), away score (second digit), and where in the game it is (in parenthesis). This is the RegEx I have currently, but am feeling is very wrong.

```
preg_match_all('/mlb_s_left[0-9]=(?P<hometeam>.*?) (?P<homescore>.*?)   (?P<awayteam>.*?) (?P<awayscore>.*?)\((?P<time>.*?)\)/', $content, $matches);
```

I would appreciate any and all help in getting this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested following code snippet in php 5.4.5:

```
    <?php
$foo = 'mlb_s_left1=Baltimore 3   ^NY Yankees 12 (FINAL)&mlb_s_right1_1=W: Hughes L: Britton&mlb_s_right1_count=1&mlb_s_url1=http://sports.espn.go.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=320801110&mlb_s_left2=^Chicago Sox 3   Minnesota 2 (FINAL)&mlb_s_right2_1=W: Peavy L: Diamond S: Reed&mlb_s_right2_count=1&mlb_s_url2=http://sports.espn.go.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=320801109';
preg_match_all('/mlb_s_left\d=\^?(?P<hometeam>[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+(?P<homescore>\d+)\s+\^?(?P<awayteam>[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+(?P<awayscore>\d+)\s+\((?P<time>\w+)\)/', $foo, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => mlb_s_left1=Baltimore 3   ^NY Yankees 12 (FINAL)
            [hometeam] => Baltimore
            [1] => Baltimore
            [homescore] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [awayteam] => NY Yankees
            [3] => NY Yankees
            [awayscore] => 12
            [4] => 12
            [time] => FINAL
            [5] => FINAL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => mlb_s_left2=^Chicago Sox 3   Minnesota 2 (FINAL)
            [hometeam] => Chicago Sox
            [1] => Chicago Sox
            [homescore] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [awayteam] => Minnesota
            [3] => Minnesota
            [awayscore] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [time] => FINAL
            [5] => FINAL
        )

)
```

Comment: You could also do something like `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` for matching the team name.

Comment: @LoneShepherd: That would match the score, too (`\w` matches digits as well as letters).  Then it would have to backtrack to match it in the "score" group instead.  The way he did it is best IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get you close.

```
preg_match_all('/mlb_s_left\d+=(?P<hometeam>\D+)\s+(?P<homescore>\d+)\s+(?P<awayteam>\D+)\s+(?P<awayscore>\d+)\s*\((?P<time>[^)]+)\)/',
    $content, $matches);
```

Note that `\d` matches any digit, and `\D` matches anything that is **not** a digit.

`[^)]+` matches one or more non-close parens characters; `\s+` matches one or more whitespace chars, and `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.

This wouldn't work very well if you have a city name with a number in it, and if you have a huge string, it's possible it could get hung up somewhere; you might consider splitting it up and matching a bit more piecemeal.

Generally speaking I would avoid `.*?` as a pattern match, as it basically matches almost anything.  It's best for your regular expression to be as specific as possible, based on what you know about the data.

Comment: I agree about `.*?`: people tend to rely on it too much.  Being as specific as you can has several benefits: you're more likely to get the correct result, you're less likely to run into performance problems, and you learn more about how regexes work.